# still getting "The parameter app_id is required" error on Facebook API login

Tags: php, facebook, api, authentication

I cannot get the FB API example to work.
I have my app registered (tried both sandbox and standard mode),
I provided `appId` and `appSecret` when instantiating the facebook object, but when I click the login link I still get the error `The parameter app_id is required`.

My php code (in config.php I define APP_ID and APP_SECRET):

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

//Including facebook php sdk file
require '../classes/Facebook.php';

//Creating our application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => APP_ID,
        'secret' => APP_SECRET
));


//Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}


// Login or logout url will (depending on current user state)
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test FB</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
        <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture" style="width:25px; height: 25px; margin-top: 7px;" />
        <a style="color:#fff;"><?php echo $user_profile['name'] ?></a>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
    <?php endif ?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this in config.php

```
define("APP_ID", "3983####90");
```

Comment: as I wrote before, I provided appId ... I meant that I have both APP_ID and APP_SECRET defined in the config.php - the issue must be something else

Comment: are you get facebook class object?