# getLoginUrl : The parameter app_id is required

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to integrate facebook authentication in a php website.

I used below code:

```
<?php
    require '../facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';

    $app_id = 'some app id';
    $app_secret = 'some secret';
    $app_url = 'http://localhost/some app/';
    $scope = 'email,publish_actions';

    // Init the Facebook SDK
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                                   'appId'  => $app_id,
                                   'secret' => $app_secret,
                                   ));

    // Get the current user
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    // If the user has not installed the app, redirect them to the Login Dialog
    if ($user <> '0' && $user <> '') { /*if valid user id i.e. neither 0 nor blank nor null*/
        try {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                                                 'scope' => $scope,
                                                 'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
                                                 ));
        die('<script>top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl($params).'";</script>');
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) { /*sometimes it shows user id even if user in not logged in and it results in Oauth exception. In this case we will set it back to 0.*/
            error_log($e);
            $user = '0';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'user not found';
    }
?>
```

Problem is:

> Though I am specifying and using correct app id, I am always getting
>   this error message- **The parameter app_id is required.**

I think I am facing similar problem- [till getting “The parameter app_id is required” error on Facebook API login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915180/still-getting-the-parameter-app-id-is-required-error-on-facebook-api-login), but there is no accepted answer to that question.

Please suggest if I am missing anything.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `appId` by `app_id` in the `new Facebook()` statement?

Comment: hey thanks.. now I am not getting that error :-) .. but now it is displaying this message: user not found... again lost :-(

Comment: btw I was following this tutorial.. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/canvas-games/authenticate/ .. do you think it is really required for me to replace appId by app_id ? It the tutorial they are using - appId

Answer (score 0):

The parameter should be `appId` as you've set in `new Facebook(...);`.

You can also try to override it by calling the following immediately after to see if it resolves the issue:

```
$facebook->setAppId('some app id');
```